# How to download images on from server to another server?

Tags: php, csv

I need to make CSV file upload for eshop. I have goods in CSV files. They have images defined for example: http://www.servername/pictures/pic1.jpg
I am finding any function, I need that script upload a CSV (solved), open CSV and explode by ",[coma]" (solved), the script go to the link with image [another server], download it and save it into directory at my server. 
Colleges helped me, that I should use get_file_contents() function, but on php.net in manual I find another things. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
if (($handle = fopen("upload/myCSV.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
 $imageUrl = $data[1];
 $contents = file_get_contents(trim($imageUrl));
 if ($contents) {
   file_put_contents('/path/to/save/pic.jpg', $contents);
 }
 fclose($handle);
}
```

In myCSV.csv file data is

"1","http://imagesus.homeaway.com/mda01/5fe39690-1cbf-469d-8525-b946ad1f4ba7.1.10"

Answer (score 0):

The basic procedure is:

```
// get the image data
$image = file_get_contents('http://www.servername/pictures/pic1.jpg');

// write the image data
$fp = fopen('path_to_your_image_folder/pic1.jpg', 'w'); //not URL
fwrite($fp, $image);
fclose($fp);
```

You will probably have to add some validation checks to check if the folder is writable, if there is content in $image and so on.